# A-Frame box transparent with texture

Tags: aframe

First, i'm sorry for my bad english, i'm french.

I would like know how can I add a texture (picture is a transparent gif), and "hide" the box to see only the texture.

Best regards

Comment: What did you try? Show some code, point out whats not working, mabye get help

Comment: I try visible=false, color=none, transparent etc...

Answer (score 5):

texture the box, and make the transparent parts transparent:
`<a-entity material="src:linkToYourTexture;transparent:true >"`

additionaly, try using .png's, not .gif's. There is a separate [component](https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-shader) for gif's tho.

transparent .png:
https://jsfiddle.net/z0fyxhv6/1/

Comment: Hi, thank for your help, but it's doesn't work

<img id="testtranspa" src="test.png">
<a-box position="0 1.4 -3" rotation="0 0 0" depth="1" width="1" height="1" material="src:#testtranspa;transparent:true"></a-box>

Comment: your img is in the assets ? - https://jsfiddle.net/z0fyxhv6/2/ moreover, are you sure test.png is the correct directory ?